How can we interpret Cgd in parallel with Cds in the buck circuit?
From this document, it's straightforward to see why Cds is included there because it's in parallel with the high-side switch, and its energy will be dissipated via the Ron of the switch when it's turned on. However, why is Cgd included there? How can we consider it as parallel with the Cds (as in the formula)?



I assume these are turn-on losses for the high-side transistor, meaning the transistor is off (while freewheeling from the low-side is active) and it G-S potential is 0 V, meaning the gate is at the source potential, and the two caps are in parallel. Both capacitors are charged at the input voltage and need to discharge. However, this capacitance is highly nonlinear and using the classical formula leads to an higher loss than reality. See slide 18 of my APEC 2011 seminar.

@VerbalKint Thanks, that makes sense. However, I've come across many sources stating that the energy in the capacitor Cds is dissipated as heat when the transistor is ON. Would that be correct?

Yes, as a first approximation, the energy stored in $C_{DS}$ dissipates as heat in the transistor but, again, either you use the formula I gave in the seminar or you use an equivalent drain-source capacitance given in the data-sheets (ST gives it for instance). Its charge corresponds to the total charge dissipated when the drain-source voltage goes from say 600 V to a few volts.
